# what is the best way to handle defines in system verilog/uvm

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a verification component which is used by many teams. I have a `define` say `ADDRESS_WIDTH` and i set it to the max of all the requirements from all the teams.

But that does not look like the ideal solution. Is there a way this can be handled in the SV/UVM way.

I thought of couple of ways

- I list this as a `parameter` in the agent so that people can use `defparams` to update it, but then also I would need a way to handle `interfaces` separately.

This leaves a potential hole, where someone might update one place and not change another place.

- There is also a command line option to update a define, but that is not ideal solution if the parameter list is too many.
- I can have a separate `defines` file and everyone can have their own `defines` file, but that would depend on the compilation order.

Please let me know what other better solutions are there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about defining the parameters in a `package` then reference it from there? Classes defined in the same package can reference the parameter without `::`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `package` to define the parameters that both the `interface` and verification component will use and therefor keep in sync. Each team can modify the package to suit their needs.

Create another package that specifies the legal range of values for those parameters and have either the interface or verification use assertions to check the values of the team's package.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Thanks a lot.